# Tkinter: Configuring multiple buttons with images

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function that takes the names of image files and creates a grid of them as buttons using the `image` attribute, which is where the issue arises, since I need the button object to create the image due to another function of mine `fit_image()` (which in this case fits the image inside the object completely, hence `full=True`). The result of running this without adding the images to these buttons is fine and all the buttons are clickable:

```
        self.image_buttons = {}
        count = 0

        # goes by column
        for y in range(height_divisor):
            # row
            for x in range(width_divisor):
                self.image_buttons[count] = tk.Button(self.preview_frame)
                self.image_buttons[count].place(
                    relx=0 + (1 / width_divisor * x),
                    rely=0 + (1 / height_divisor * y),
                    relwidth=1 / width_divisor,
                    relheight=1 / height_divisor,
                    anchor="nw",
                )

                # self.current_image = fit_image(
                #     Image.open(names_of_files[count]), self.image_buttons[count], full=True
                # )

                # self.image_buttons[count].configure(image=self.current_image)
                count += 1
                

        print(self.image_buttons)
```

Result of print statement:

```
{0: <tkinter.Button object .!toplevel2.!frame2.!button>, 1: <tkinter.Button object .!toplevel2.!frame2.!button2>, 2: <tkinter.Button object .!toplevel2.!frame2.!button3>, 3: <tkinter.Button object .!toplevel2.!frame2.!button4>}
```

However, once I uncomment this code, only the last button is clickable and **does have** the image on it, but all the others are blank and not clickable buttons. I have tried putting the commented (image configuration) lines in a separate for loop afterwards to go through and configure each button to no avail. Though I've previously had this work and even tried combing through [my repo](https://github.com/Daggerpov/background-revolution/commits/main)'s commits (nothing before Aug 8th should be relevant) to see how it worked before, it must've been working then I most likely broke it before committing.

Comment: How do you know the button isn't clickable? It doesn't have a command or any bindings associated with it. Links to code on another site are discouraged here. Please [edit]  your question to include a complete [mcve].

Comment: You have to *keep a reference* to each PhotoImage object to keep it alive - you're overwriting `self.current_image` on each iteration, so only the most recent image still exists.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, I may be wrong about them being buttons but my reasoning was that the last one makes the default button clicking animation and the others don't. Should I add the calculations for my `width/height_divisor` variables and the `fit_image()` function to make it complete? For the `names_of_files` it should work with the path of images files on your computer, that I got through my GUI using `filedialog.askopenfilenames()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved thanks to @jasonharper 's comment by changing these two lines and adding a new dictionary:

```
        self.image_buttons, self.images = {}, {}
        #for loops here

                self.images[count] = fit_image(
                    Image.open(names_of_files[count]), self.image_buttons[count], full=True
                )

                self.image_buttons[count].configure(image=self.images[count])
```